# Instruct stack to use the already installed MinGW

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I have msys2 installed separately from GHC. MinGW toolchain is installed inside of the msys environment. Now I'm running into issues with some native libraries that work when I use them outside of Haskell, but don't work when ran from Haskell code.

The problem is that commands like `stack exec` and `stack repl` prepend GHC's MinGW folders to the PATH and then you get things like one dynamic library being found in my msys installation, while it's dependency is first found in GHC's MinGW installation and the whole thing doesn't work.

Stack provides a `skip-msys` option to avoid using the msys environment that it installs, but as far as I can tell there's no way to skip the GHC-provided MinGW toolchain.

What can I do about this?

Comment: You should probably use the MinGW which is installed with GHC. There are minuscule differences between different versions of MinGW and the one shipping with GHC is the one it relies on getting (if you system version and the GHC version are identical, then I don't see how the behavior would differ). You've stated the actual problem - "issues with some native libraries .. [that] .. don't work when ran from Haskell code" - it may be more fruitful to try to fix this problem rather than work around it. I've had such a problem before, and that was the eventual solution (not using system MinGW).

Comment: @user2407038 The solution in this case is replacing the zlib1.dll in GHC's MinGW with a newer version. I'm fine with GHC using it's own DLLs, but there should be no reason to pollute the path. I'm guessing a lot of packages wouldn't compile because they also rely on those DLLs, but why not at least APPEND to the PATH instead of prepending so there's a chance of overriding?